# Перенаправленние на GET запрос / .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Добрый вечере, уважаемые программисты.
Появилась такая задача, все запросы типа:

```
http://site.ru/test1/
http://site.ru/Otv/
http://site.ru/saying/
```

и т.д. перенаправлять в соответствии:

```
http://site.ru?code=test1
http://site.ru?code=Otv
http://site.ru?code=saying
```

вот, что получились:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/$ ?code=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Т.е. нужно, чтобы в браузере была, к примеру строка http://site.ru/test1/, но фактически на сервере был один файл index.php, который подобный запрос воспринимал также как http://site.ru?code=test1

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не верно?
Спасибо

Comment: `/` в начале шаблона?

Comment: вообще было бы неплохо, если бы вы написали, что именно не работает или какая ошибка возникает

Comment: перехожу по адресу http://site.ru/test1/  , выдает 404 ошибку

Comment: В htaccess `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://site.ru/%1/ [L,QSA]`

Comment: дак убрали `/` то?